# Memory usage of aliasing and embedding

Tags: go

Is there a difference in memory usage between an alias type (1)

```
type String1 string
```

and an embedded type (2)

```
type String2 struct {
    string
}
```

I think the second example contains two pointers: `String2` has a pointer to `string` and `string` has a pointer to the UTF-8 bytes.

Is it the same in example 1?

Comment: Why would `String2` have a pointer to `string`?

Comment: @Adrian https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#embedding says: "When we embed a type, the methods of that type become methods of the outer type, but when they are invoked the receiver of the method is the inner type, not the outer one." I can not see any other way to distinguish between the inner and outer type.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - the docs don't call it a pointer there, and it isn't a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A struct value in Go is not a reference. It is a block of memory containing the struct fields (and possibly holes caused by alignment).

So values of both types should look the same in memory.

It's easy to verify:
https://go.dev/play/p/syrAPVsCWfS

Answer (score 0):

Embedding by default does not introduce a pointer.
With a pointer it would be

```
type String2 struct {
    *string
}
```

Comment: It may be not visible, but I think it still must be there. How to distinguish inner and outer type otherwise?

Comment: Why must there be a pointer? This is part of the type system, handled by the compiler, it is not something dealt with at runtime.

Comment: @JimB Methods of the inner type receive a inner type struct. Methods of the outer type receive a outer type struct. How can this be the same?

Comment: @ceving, sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. I think there's some misunderstanding about what types are that is making this hard to comunicate

Comment: @ceving When you call a method that belongs to an embedded type, the value of the relevant struct field will be used as the receiver of the method, not the full struct value. Note that the receiver will be passed by value just like any argument.